# obfs4proxy installation

Tags: obfs4proxy

first of all, thanks for reading my post!i am asking this question: to install obfs4proxy on a ubuntu mate armhf raspberry 4b, i tried some methods.

the first one is to install from ubuntu package archive.i searched by obfs4proxy at packages.ubuntu.com and found its available at ubt focal（20.04）universe and here is my /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main universe restricted multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main universe restricted multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main universe restricted multiverse

the questions is where i run apt search obfs4proxy i got no hint on whatever could be found there, and i noticed there were some igt hints when i tried to run sudo apt update, could it probably be that universe version of maintainance was ignored by some reason?

the second method is to try to compile it myself when i find that proxy.golang.org block by isp

so i will stil try the first method,can anyone tell me how i can search for package obfs4proxy or any ppa available?

Comment: i noticed that this is a armhf based raspberry pi system, os i switched to port.ubuntu.com  deb http://ports.ubuntu.com focal main universe restricted multiverse                                      i also checked the Package definition whereii found obfs4proxy package however apt search obfs4proxy still gave no output from the source

Comment: i tried sudo apt update and found there were errors starting with E: could it be that the errors stopped system from refreshing repositories and i was actually using system default configuration?

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions provided here - https://community.torproject.org/relay/setup/bridge/debian-ubuntu/ and see if it

Comment: thanks, i manually pulled the installation package out of pool and did a dpkg install, that worked for me. and for missing golang pack i cloned that on github